# Django - Reference data from another model using a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django so please tell me if I'm not on the right track.
I have a Django project that I'm building and just wanted to ask what is the correct Django way to retrieve data from one model and use it in another.

I have a for loop to assign the required fields to variables but I was looking for a cleaner solution and if one exists, one that uses the foreign key.

Here's an example of the code involved:

```
#MODELS

class Class1(models.Model):
    tag_number = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    example1 =  models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    example2 =  models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)

class Class2(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Class1, related_name = 'tag_foreignkey')
    example3 =  models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    example4 =  models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)



#VIEWS - This view is for Class2 but referencing fields from Class1

tag_number = str(instrumentform.cleaned_data['tag'])
query_results = Class1.objects.filter(tag_number = tag_number)
for query_result in query_results:
        example5 = query_result.example1
        example6 = query_result.example2
```

The above works but I assume it's not the Django way of doing things and is not taking advantage of the foreign key.

If someone could give me a nudge in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might be looking for ManyToMany relationship in Django. Please look at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still, not hundred percent know what you want, since there are some missing info out there.
For you Class1, You should do what you have done to Class2, using foreign key to store tag.

For you code at bottom, there is a easy way to do it. (Assume you have used foreign key)

```
tag_number = int(instrumentform.cleaned_data['tag'])
for query_result in Class1.objects.filter(tag = tag_number).values_list('example1', 'exmaple2'):
    example5, example6 = query_result
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. I am imagining that PstCalc = Class1
Nevertheless, if you have

```
c1 = Class1()
c2 = Class2()
c3 = Class2()
and
c2.tag = c1
c3.tag = c1
```

using the foreignkey you would have:

```
c1.class2_set = (c2, c3) <- this would be a queryset, not a list
c2.tag = c1 => c2.tag.example1 = c1.example1
```

...hope I made my self understood :)